# Почему не могу вернуть id юзера из базы?

Tags: python, flask

Разбираюсь с flask, передо мной стоит задача реализации авторизации не через браузер, а клиент, написанный на PyQt. Во фреймворке flask при авторизации пользователя, который был зарегистрирован и находится в базе SQLite есть фрагмент кода, отвечающий за авторизацию, который я чуть переделал:

```
@bp.route('/login', methods=('GET', 'POST'))
def login():
    if request.method == 'POST':
        username = request.get_json().get('username')
        password = request.get_json().get('password')

        #return username
        db = get_db()
        error = None
        user = db.execute(
            'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = ?', (username,)
        ).fetchone()
        #return user['id']

        if user is None:
            error = 'Incorrect username.'
        elif not check_password_hash(user['password'], password):
            error = 'Incorrect password.'

        if error is None:
            #session.clear()
            #session['user_id'] = user['id']
            return user['id']
            #return user['username']

    return error
```

Возвращаемое значение я могу получать в терминале, если возвращаю user['username'] или user['password'] - с этим все нормально, запрос нормально выполняется с кодом 200, но не могу вернуть user['id'] - получаю ошибку сервера 500, что мне кажется странным и непонятным, ведь id в базе есть. Подскажите, в чем может быть причина?

Comment: Надо заковычить имя в запросе 'SELECT * FROM user WHERE username = \'?\'

Comment: Может у вас нет в базе колонки id? Потому что, если `user['password']` работает, а `user['id']` нет, то колонка `password` есть, а `id` - нет

Comment: suit В том-то и странность, что есть колонка id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, но не могу ее получить...

Comment: Alexander Chernin  к сожалению, это не помогает, если заковычить, то всегда получаю ошибку 500

Comment: Ошибка 500 обязательно сопровождается текстом в логе ошибок, покажите текст ошибки

Comment: andreymal Спасибо) как-то я ступил и не догадался лог посмотреть, оказывается возвращаются только строковые значения, а id число, поэтому и была проблема, в виде строки возвращает